# Question about Billing of Google Cloud Projects

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, android-billing

I am here because I have a question about the billing of the google cloud project. First of all I am still a student and I am developing my own mobile application which needs an access to the google maps and maps directions api. My problem is a can't access the directions and it says that I need to setup or enabled the billing options. I just want to know how does the google charges me when I enabled the billing? And does it automatically charges me right after I enabled it even though I am still developing my application? Thank you for your answers and time! Hope have all a great Day!

Comment: Here is a link to a videolab on Google Cloud Billing. These short videos will help you understand how billing works and save you from billing surprises: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of a service and not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to setup a billing account, there is no way around it. As long as you keep under the limits Google won't charge you anything. Since you are developing your own project you are unlikely to hit the limit, which is currently 5000 Hits per month.